# IntelliJ exclude folder from exploded war

Tags: java, intellij-idea, war, intellij-14

We have a java web project in IntelliJ (Ultimate 14.1.14) and we want to exclude a certain folder from the exploded war.

Using a maven profile we created the folder gets excluded from the generated war file, but we need to exclude it in the exploded war too, when running the project using IntelliJ.

Project's Run Configuration: [Project's run configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NluO.png)

We tried different approaches such as marking the folder as excluded in Project Structure > Modules window, and also in Settings > Build, Execution, Development > Compiler > Excludes but nothing worked.

Does anyone know how we can do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try going to:

```
Project Structure -> Artifacts
```

Select the exploded .war, go to the `Output Layout` tab and configure your desired layout.

Comment: Ok, we tried that but the problem is that at `Output Layout` tab our gui module, that includes the folder that we want to exclude (gui\src\main\webapp\resources\sencha), cannot be expanded in order to select the folder we want.